# When would O(n*n) be quicker then O (log n)?

Tags: performance, big-o

I have this question on a practice test and I'm not sure of when code would run quicker on O(n*n) over O(log n).

Answer (score 6):

Big oh notation gives upper bounds. Not more.

If algorithm A is `O(n ^ 2)`, it could require exactly `n ^ 2` steps.

If algorithm B is `O(log n)`, it could require exactly `10000 * log n` steps.

Algorithm A is a lot faster than algorithm B for small `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Big-O is the upper bound. It's quite possible that because of constants that under smaller input sizes the O(n^2) algorithm can run faster than O(log n). It could be entirely possible that in most cases the n^2 can also run faster and that algorithm happens to run in n^2 only because of certain input sets that cause it to have to do a lot of work.

Comment: Excluding the specifics of various algorithms, no input exists where `n*n` is smaller than `log n`.  Please see graph.

Comment: Yes it is possible because Big-O removes all constants so its possible that it could be 100000000*logn + some large constant and a basic n^2 algorithm. N^2 is also the upper bound, in the average case the algorithm could perform in loglogn time or something like that.

Comment: I am focusing on the input sizes, not the specifics (the constraints you mentioned) of an algorithm.  If there are two algorithms, one with a running time of exactly `n*n` and the other with a running time of exactly `log n` then there exists no `n` value where `n*n` can be will be faster than `log n`.

Comment: @typoknig For Big-O notation yes, you are removing the constraints on the question and making an entirely different question. It means the UPPER BOUND which means you need to take into account specifics. It is also only high N behavior which means that for small N it does not necessarily hold.

Comment: In fairness you are correct, it is *possible*, but highly improbable, even for the smallest of `n` values. A `log n` algorithm would have to implement its constraints in a grossly inefficient fashion to ever be slower than the most efficient `n*n` algorithm. In fact, I think a person would actually have to try and make the `log n` algorithm inefficient for this to even be in the realm of possibility. I *would* challenge you to show me any implementation of insertion sort that was faster than a `log n` sorting algorithm, but since no `log n` sorting algorithm exists it is kinda a moot point :)

Comment: @typoknig There are actually implementations and products out there that will actually use O(n^2) algorithms over something like O(nlogn) because they perform better on average and the amortized cost would be lower. Usually you will see that for small n people may prefer algorithms with better average time than looking at something with low Big-O because they know input will never exceed a certain amount.

Comment: Yeah, I actually had a homework assignment once where I had to make insertion sort faster than merge sort. Easy enough with a small data set, but `n log n` is an entirely different time complexity than `log n`, and the difference is huge. An `n log n` and `n*n` algorithm are not that far apart, but a `log n` and an `n*n` algorithm are far apart, far enough apart that it is very unlikely said `log n` algorithm would ever be slower than said `n*n` algorithm, but I get where you are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I am retracting my previous answer of never because technically it is possible for a `O(n*n)` algorithm to be faster than a `O(log n)` algorithm, though highly improbably.  See my discussion with Jesus under his answer for more details.  The graph below shows that an algorithm that has a time complexity of *exactly* `log n` is always faster than an algorithm that has a time complexity of *exactly* `n*n`.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if they meant log2n. Isn't log10n ?

Comment: When discussing time complexity of algorithms we always refer to base 2, not base 10.

Comment: This is not true as Big-O removes all constants and factors from the leading term which means that it's completely possible.

Comment: @JesusRamos See my comments under your answer.